# VFS: URL parameter transport.vfs.passive not working in WSO2 EI 6.2.0

Tags: wso2, vfs, passive-mode

Good morning

I have a proxy service that read file from a FTP that require passive move. In WSO2 EI 6.1.0,  I was able to enable passive mode via URL parameter 
`?transport.vfs.passive=true` and it worked without problem.

In WSO2 EI 6.2.0, the same proxy service fails with following error
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory SYST
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory 215 UNIX Type: L8
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory PORT192,168,200,195,223,83
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory LIST OUT/VERIFY/IN
[EI-Core] DEBUG - FtpClientFactory$FtpConnectionFactory 425 Failed to establish connection.

The main difference in log, is ftp answer 
**200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.**

Did the parameter to enable passive mode change between vfs and vfs2,  or is there another way to enable passive mode in VFS FTP in WSO2 EI 6.2.0
**edit, I tried also ?vfs.passive=true with same result**

For Reference, the code I used to test this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="FTP_Test" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log category="WARN" level="custom">
                <property name="Status" value="FTP processing"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI"> vfs:ftp://xxx:xxx@192.168.10.100:21/OUT/VERIFY/IN?transport.vfs.passive=true
</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.*</parameter>   
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/2345 regarding this. This is due to some query parameters were not taken into account. We have fixed this issue in a consequtive release.